# Styles in Word 2013 Keep Reverting to Previous Style/Format/Indent

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2013, styles

I am working on a document that relies on formatting consistency throughout all chapters/sections.

The indents keep changing, even after I have made the changes in **Modify** and

**Update <   > to Match Selection**.

How can I "fix" the indents, spacing and hanging paragraphs so they don't change?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your reference to 'hanging paragraphs' makes me think that list styles, specifically, are causing the issue. Is that the case, or are other styles involved too? If lists, have you defined your own list styles, are you using the predefined list styles (e.g., List Bullet, List Number), or are you just using the Bullets/Numbering buttons on the ribbon? If other styles, which ones?

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes from work with Word 2010, but I believe it still applies in 2013.

You should modify the style that you're using directly. Right click on it in the styles list and edit its properties; indentation, spacing, and paragraph formatting are all choices there.

Also check to make sure that when you move to another part of the document, that you are not moving into a region with a different style already applied; this will change the style your cursor will apply. If your document will use only one style throughout, it is possible to select the whole document with Cntrl+A and then apply your custom style to it by clicking on it in the style menu.